# Google analytics android app not showing Firebase property

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics

I've been using Analytics to track my application usage since a couple of years. I was suggested by Google to change the tracking to Firebase as the Analytics API will be de-supported. I changed it and in Firebase console I was asked to link my app to Analytics and once I did it I got a new property in Analytics web. Everything is tracked correctly but I want to view my statistics in the Android app of Google Analytics. The problem is that the properties created by the link with Firebase are not visible in the app. Could you suggest a way to change that?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and its very frustrating